# How to set the 'UIDevice.currentDevice()' for object of notification?

Tags: ios, notifications, swift, uidevice

When I add a notification for device orientation Changed, like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: Selector(layoutPages),
        name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification as String!,
        object: UIDevice.currentDevice())
```

I get a error 'UIDevice is not identical to anyobject', so how to fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your second argument, it should be a string. Also, upcasting the UIDevice to AnyObject will help:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
    selector: Selector("layoutPages"),
        name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification as NSString!,
      object: UIDevice.currentDevice() as AnyObject)
```